# Неправильный вывод массива (результат все нули)

Tags: c++

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <iomanip.h>

int main()
{
    int A[5];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 5)
    {
        A[i] = 0;
        i++;
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    cout << "vash massiv: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << ' ';         
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас в while какая-то ересь написана

Comment: @AlexeyTen все исправил

Comment: Так вы же сами своими руками обнуляете весь массив в цикле ввода, затирая введенные пользователем значения. Вот и выводятся потом "все нули". Ничего удивительного. И что такое `<vcl.h>`, `<iostream.h>` и `<iomanip.h>`? И к чему здесь `<math.h>`?

Answer (score 2):

В цикле:

```
while (i < 5) {
    A[ i ] = 0;
    i++;
    cin>>A[i]; // тут i == 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;        
}
```

вы не инициализируете первый элемент и пытаетесь инициализировать элемент за концом цикла. Исправьте на:

```
while (i < 5) {        
   cin>>A[i++];        
}
```

Абсолютно не нужно инициализировать элемент два раза. А то у вас получается, что вы элемент инициализируете нулем, а следующий элемент вводите, потом этот же элемент опять инициализируете нулем и вводите значение третьего и т. д.